# How to find the longest line in a file using bash script?

Tags: bash

can anyone give a look to this bash script of mine please? I am trying to find the longest line in a file using a bash script so I wrote this.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Francesco Foschi length of a row in a file

let n=0
let max_length=0

while read row
do
    length=$(echo -n $row | wc -c)
    if[ ${#length} -gt ${#max_length} ]
    then
            let max_length=${#length}
    fi

    echo "$n row is $length charachters long"
    echo "$row"
    let n=n+1

done < $1

echo "longest line is $max_length charachters long"

exit 0
```

Every time I try to run the console says that I have a syntax error near the unexpected *then* token. What am I doing wrong??

*BTW running of fedora28*

Comment: You should put a space after the word `if`.

Comment: I suggest you to check your code in https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: `length="${#row}"`

Comment: Bash is a supremely slow and tacky tool for this particular task. You want to investigate reimplementing the script in Awk for any real-world scenario.

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit. Questions on Stack Overflow should remain strictly questions; the way to mark something as a suitable answer is simply to accept an answer, like you already did. (The [question's edit history](/posts/53459879/revisions) still contains all the text if you want to recover it.)

Comment: Also check the spelling of *"characters"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Francesco Foschi length of a row in a file

let n=0
let max_length=0

while read row
do
    length=$(echo -n $row | wc -c)
    if [ ${length} -gt ${max_length} ]
    then
            let max_length=${length}
    fi

    echo "$n row is $length charachters long"
    echo "$row"
    let n=n+1

done < $1

echo "longest line is $max_length charachters long"

exit 0
```

Answer (score 5):

GNU `wc` has this functionality built in:

```
-L, --max-line-length
        print the maximum display width
```

Comment: I knew this but I am trying to go full POSIX

Answer (score 2):

plain bash

```
#!/bin/bash
max=-1
while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ ${#line} -gt $max ]] && max=${#line}
done < "$1"
echo "longest line is $max chars long"
```

---

This idiom is used to read the line exactly verbatim: `IFS= read -r line`

Demo:

1. create a file with leading/trailing whitespace and a backslash

   ```
   $ echo ' h\bHello ' > file
   ```

   this file is 10 bytes in size (not counting the trailing newline).
2. read it with plain `read var`

   ```
   $ read line < file; printf %s "$line" | od -c
   0000000   h   b   H   e   l   l   o
   0000007
   ```

   Only 7 chars: missing the backslash and the whitespace
3. add the `-r` option for read:

   ```
   $ read -r line < file; printf %s "$line" | od -c
   0000000   h   \   b   H   e   l   l   o
   0000010
   ```

   Now we have 8 characters (the "0000010" is octal), but still missing the whitespace.
4. add the `IFS=` variable assignment:

   ```
   $ IFS= read -r line < file; printf %s "$line" | od -c
   0000000       h   \   b   H   e   l   l   o    
   0000012
   ```

   10 characters (octal 12): now we have exactly what was written to the file in $line.

It's a pain to have to write `IFS= read -r line` all the time, but bash inflicts considerable pain on the programmer.